# Configure Gradle connection timeout

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When Gradle tries to retrieve a dependency from a Repository and the Repository does not react, Gradle times out after a very long time. I want to fail fast in case of problems.

Is it possible to configure the connection timeout in Gradle to fail fast?

Comment: Are you behind the firewall or proxy?

Comment: No, i'm not behind a proxy. The Artifactory machine i'm using is sometimes very slow and only responses in 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The current timeout is at 3 minutes and is not configurable. There is an [open issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2345) for this in the tracker. You should vote for the issue.